# En-queueing Protocol Buffer messages with RabbitMQ Manager

Tags: rabbitmq, protocol-buffers

I'm able to queue messages as strings on my queue via the RabbitMQ Manager.  My problem is that my app will be using Protocol Buffers and I can't figure out how to queue the raw bytes of a protocol buffer.  I'm able to en-queue and de-queue protocol buffer messages through my app but I want to be able to queue messages through the RabbitMQ Manager and de-queue via my app.

I found this tool called Protocol Buffers Workbench (http://blog.functionalfun.net/2010/10/getting-started-with-protocol-buffers.html) which will convert my message to raw bytes.  I can't however figure out how to take the raw bytes and en-queue them through the RabbitMQ Manager.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find an easy way to do this so I wrote my own program to do it for me:

https://github.com/thereallisa/proto_enqueue